# How to determine if your server is running "Ubuntu Pro"?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I've taken over administering an EC2 instance created by someone who's left the company. I understand that the server may be operating [Ubuntu Pro](https://ubuntu.com/aws/pro) but am having trouble working out how to check. I've tried the following:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.3.0-1023-aws (buildd@lcy01-amd64-022) (gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)) #25~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 5 15:18:30 UTC 2020
```

Is there a way to check on the server or is this something that can be checked in the AWS Console?

**Update: I was able to find that the following was seemingly enabled which may only be available to Ubuntu Pro but I'm not certain**

```
$ canonical-livepatch status
last check: 46 minutes ago
kernel: 5.3.0-1023.25~18.04.1-aws
server check-in: succeeded
patch state: ✓ no livepatches needed for this kernel yet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a marketplace product, you can go to [AWS Marketplace Subscriptions](https://console.aws.amazon.com/marketplace/home?region=us-west-2#/subscriptions) to see what marketplace products are currently running.

You should also be able to tell from the AMI. If you look at the instance details in the EC2 console, there is an AMI field. If you click the AMI name, it may say if it is Ubuntu Pro or not.

You may also be able to tell by looking at your AWS Bill. This marketplace product appears to have an extra cost (albeit small). It may not tell you *which* instance though, in case you are running more than one in the account.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the the marketplace product code that your instance is using with the following methods:

With Instance Metadata Service (IMDS) version 1:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document
```

With IMDSv2:

```
TOKEN=`curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600"` \
&& curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document
```

This command also works for me:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/product-codes
```

This will return a product code like abwe6hiebq70xss7fo2neefpy and you can then go to `https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp?sku=<product code here>` which will return an AWS marketplace page like "Ubuntu Pro 20.04 LTS".